# Inner select syntax error in sql where clause

Tags: sql, left-join, where-clause

I have two tables.

- `TblA`  has columns: StudentName, StudentID, FeeRateID, CourseType, CourseSpeciality.

  `StudentGender.CourseType` has 3 categories (Computer Science, Social Studies and Literary Studies). `CourseSpeciality` (under Computer Science) has 4 different categories (Java, Python, SQL, R).Social studies has 2 and Literary studies has 2 `CourseSpecialities`.
- Table `TbLB` has StudentID, DateOfRegistration, FeeRateID.

I need to join the two tables to get `StudentName, FeeRate, FeeRateID` for administrative purpose. I am told to join two tables to obtain the details for all students. Literary and Social Studies students’ all CourseSpecialty has to be included.

But I am asked to include Computer Science students with CourseSpecialty of Java, Python and R.

I tried this, but my code throws a syntax error. I know problem lies in the inner select (`Where` clause) but I'm not able to fix this on my own. Can someone help me please?

```
SELECT
    A.StudentName, A.StudentID, A.CourseType, B.FeeRateID
FROM
    A
LEFT JOIN
    B ON a.FeeRateId = b.FeeRateID
WHERE 
    A.CourseType IN ('Social Studies', 'Literary Studies', 'Computer Science' (SELECT CourseType FROM A WHERE CourseType = 'Computer Science' and CourseSpecialty IN ('Java', 'Python', R);
```

Comment: Your `IN` is malformed.  Just use two separate clauses, one for the constants and one for the subquery.

Comment: @Marc_s, would appreciate if you could code correcting  my  faulty IN part .

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand why is the subquery needed in this case at all, since it will return 'Computer Science' which is already specified in the IN(...).

```
SELECT
    A.StudentName, A.StudentID, A.CourseType, B.FeeRateID
FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON a.FeeRateId = b.FeeRateID
WHERE 
    A.CourseType IN ('Social Studies', 'Literary Studies') 
    OR 
    (A.CourseType = 'Computer Science' AND A.CourseSpecialty IN ('Java', 'Python', 'R'))
```

Comment: need to limit coursespecialty to just 3 types(java, python, r)  while Social and literary studies all course speciaty is to be obtained.

Comment: I understand that, but in your example subquery returns CourseType ('Computer Science') which is the same for all the CourseSpeciality . And you already have hardcoded value for 'Computer Science' , so I dont see any need for such subquery.